# Neo4j Client Return Unique Path on Unwind Group of nodes

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

The aim of the Cypher is to get every Node and her up to 2nd degree connections with the same sulotionId on the link property, The Nodes I want to return have several types , TypeA /TypeB all are childs of the NodeType.

My Cypher looking like this :

```
var graphResult = graphClient.Cypher
            .Unwind(Nodes, "singleNode")
            .Match("p = (innerNode:Intell{Id:singleNode.Id}) - 
            [r:CONTAINS*1..2{solutionId:{innerSolutionId}}] - ()")
            .WithParam("innerSolutionId", solutionId)
            .Return(p => new
                   {
                       Nodes = 
                    Neo4jClient.Cypher.Return.As<IEnumerable<Neo4JNodeDSO>>("nodes(p)"),
                       Relationships = Neo4jClient.Cypher.Return.As<IEnumerable<Neo4JLinkDSO>>("rels(p)")
                   }).Results;
```

But the problem is that if there 2 nodes that are connected with middle node and they are inside the group that I unwind it shows the paths 2 times (1 starting from each side ) any way to prevent that ?
Example:
A->B->C while A and C are in the grop of nodes returns :
A->B->C path and C->B->A path

Thanks a lot from advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options - first would be to assign at direction to your relationship - so:

```
p = (innerNode:Intell)-[r:CONTAINS]->()
```

which would help, though you could still get the duplicates.

[Shortest Path](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path) might be your best bet, as that will return one as opposed to multiples. So something like:

```
var graphResult = graphClient.Cypher
    .Unwind(Nodes, "singleNode")
    .Match("p = shortestPath( (innerNode:Intell{Id:singleNode.Id})-[r:CONTAINS*1..2{solutionId:{innerSolutionId}}]-() )")
    .WithParam("innerSolutionId", solutionId)
    .Return(p => new {
        Nodes = Neo4jClient.Cypher.Return.As<IEnumerable<Neo4JNodeDSO>>("nodes(p)"),
        Relationships = Neo4jClient.Cypher.Return.As<IEnumerable<Neo4JLinkDSO>>("rels(p)")
        })
    .Results;
```